# How to call function in a Powershell Write-Host statement

Tags: powershell

```
$BizTalkHelper = "d:\Scripts\BizTalkHelper.ps1"
.$BizTalkHelper # "dot source" the helper library.
Write-Host *** BEGIN ***

Write-Host $(Get-Date) " Desc:" {GetHostStateDesc 1 }
Write-Host $(Get-Date) " Desc:" GetHostStateDesc 2 

$result = GetHostStateDesc 1 
Write-Host $result
```

My functions prints "hello", in addition to a switch statement to translate 1 to 'Stopped', 2 to 'Start Pending', 4 to 'Running', etc... 
So I know it's not getting called in the first two cases.

Results:

```
*** BEGIN *** 
3/29/2013 11:03:34 AM  Desc: GetHostStateDesc 1 
3/29/2013 11:03:34 AM  Desc: GetHostStateDesc 2 
hello 
Function GetHostStateDesc  1 
Stopped
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it is this:

```
Write-Host $(Get-Date) " Desc:" $(GetHostStateDesc 1 )
```

I noticed the `$()` syntax around `Get-Date`, so if it's a function, I guessed it would work on my function and it did.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
function SayHello {'Hello'}
write-host $(SayHello)
```

This prints:

```
Hello
```

Comment: also without sub-expression `write-host (SayHello)`